# C/C++ DLL: Converting a const uint8_t to a String

Tags: c++-cli, string-conversion, ane

I haven't seen C++ code in more than 10 years and now I'm in the need of developing a very small DLL to use the [`Ping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) class `(System::Net::NetworkInformation)` to make a ping to some `remoteAddress`.

The argument where I'm receiving the `remoteAddress` is a [`FREObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WS460ee381960520ad-866f9c112aa6e1ad46-7ffa.html) which then needs to be transformed into a `const uint8_t *`. The previous is mandatory and I can't change anything from it. The `remoteAddress` has to be received as a `FREObject` and later be transformed in a `const uint8_t *`.

The problem I'm having is that I have to pass a `String^` to the `Ping` class and not a `const uint8_t *` and I have no clue of how to convert my `const uint8_t *` to a `String^`. Do you have any ideas?

Next is part of my code:

```
// argv[ARG_IP_ADDRESS_ARGUMENT holds the remoteAddress value.
uint32_t nativeCharArrayLength = 0;
const uint8_t * nativeCharArray = NULL;
FREResult status = FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[ARG_IP_ADDRESS_ARGUMENT], &nativeCharArrayLength, &nativeCharArray);
```

Basically the [`FREGetObjectAsUTF8`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSb464b1207c184b14-62b8e11f12937b86be4-7fe6.html) function fills the `nativeCharArray` array with the value of `argv[ARG_IP_ADDRESS_ARGUMENT]` and returns the array's length in `nativeCharArrayLength`. Also, the string uses UTF-8 encoding terminates with the null character.

My next problem would be to convert a `String^` back to a `const uint8_t *`. If you can help with this as well I would really appreciate it.

As I said before, non of this is changeable and I have no idea of how to change `nativeCharArray` to a `String^`. Any advice will help.

PS: Also, the purpose of this DLL is to use it as an ANE (Air Native Extension) for my Adobe Air app.

Comment: For converting the `const uint8_t` array into a string, you need to include "stdlib.h". Then, do the following: `string adrs = (const char*) nativeCharArray`. This will give you a String Object. For the other way around: the String class in stdlib.h defines a function called c_str(). You can use it like this: `const uint8_t * adrsOtherwayAround = (const uint8_t *) adrs.c_str()`

Comment: @Eregrith I'm writting a DLL in C++ but part of the code is in C.

Comment: @Storo Is your problem a C problem or a C++ problem?

Comment: `I haven't seen C++ code in more than 10 years and now`  And the code you posted in the question is not C++ (referring to `String^`).

Comment: @DodgerThud Thanks for the advice. I tried it and after including stdlib.h get the error "string" identifier not defined.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The part I put is not C++, ergo, the C tag on the question. The DLL is made in C++ but this part of the code is in C. Plus I don't think that C has `String^`, am I wrong?

Comment: @Storo `String^` does not exist in the C++ language.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It is C++/CLI. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

Comment: @Storo I know what it is.  What it is is *not* C++.  That's why I edited the tags.

Comment: @Eregrith I'm receiving the parameters in C type definitions but I need to change them to C++ type definitions in order to use the `Ping` class.

Comment: @DodgerThud I included `<string>` instead of `stdlib.h`. Also, the only thing I'm missing is the length of the new `const uint8_t *` and storing that length in a `uint32_t` variable. Do you have any idea of how to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need UTF8Encoding to convert the bytes to characters.  It has methods that take pointers, you'll want to take advantage of that.  You first need to count the number of characters in the converted string, then allocate an array to store the converted characters, then you can turn it into System::String.  Like this:

```
auto converter = gcnew System::Text::UTF8Encoding;
auto chars = converter->GetCharCount((Byte*)nativeCharArray, nativeCharArrayLength-1);
auto buffer = gcnew array<Char>(chars);
pin_ptr<Char> pbuffer = &buffer[0];
converter->GetChars((Byte*)nativeCharArray, nativeCharArrayLength-1, pbuffer, chars);
String^ result = gcnew String(buffer);
```

Note that the -1 on *nativeCharArrayLength* compensates for the zero terminator being included in the value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting your answer but I solved it using the first comment on the post, therefore, I haven't tried your solution.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't convert from utf-8 and doesn't generate a String^.  I can of course only answer the actual question asked.

Comment: You are right. I used the following: `std::string stdStringIPAddress = (const char*)nativeCharArray;
  String^ ipAddress = gcnew String(stdStringIPAddress.c_str());`. As you can see is much simpler.

Comment: Well, of course it is simpler if you completely ignore the requirement to handle utf-8 encoded text.  You'll be back.

Comment: Why do you think that I could have a problem if I'm only sending an IP address in the form of a string that has been validated before?